# PECL bb-codes installation and usage

Tags: php, bbcode

I want to use the PECL (TS) extention from https://pecl.php.net/package/bbcode/1.0.3b1/windows.
I have add the `php_bbcode.dll` in `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext` and added the extension to the dynamic extension list in `php.ini`, and by the example i have gotten (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjLKS.jpg) i have made my own bb-codes:

bb-code (PECL):

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database") or die ("Could not connect to database");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['bio_message'])){                
        $BBcode = array(
            'b' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => 'b', 'close_tag' => '/b'),
            'i' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => 'i', 'close_tag' => '/i'),
            'u' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => 'u', 'close_tag' => '/u'),
            's' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => 's', 'close_tag' => '/s'),
            'green' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => '<div class="green">', 'close_tag' => '</div>'),
            'orange' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => '<div class="orange">', 'close_tag' => '</div>'),
            'red' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => '<div class="red">', 'close_tag' => '</div>'),
            'blue' => array('type' => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG, 'open_tag' => '<div class="blue">', 'close_tag' => '</div>'),
        );

        $text = $_POST['bio_message'];
        $BBhandler = bbcode_create($BBcode);
        $htmltext = bbcode_parse($BBhandler, $text);
    }

    $id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    $bio_sql = "UPDATE users SET bio = '$htmltext' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $db->query($bio_sql);
}else{}
```

but the code wont update the database, so i am not able to test if the code even works. I cant find any tutorial online on the PECL bbcode so all i have is the one picture.

Comment: bbcode has nothing to do with databases. if you want to update a database, YOU have to write the code for that.

Comment: I know but what i mean with updateing database is wich one of the `$` am i using to update the databse? is it the `$str` or the `$htmltext` ?

Comment: honestly.. you can't even do basic debugging, like `echo $str; echo $htmltext` to see what each contains?

Comment: no because i have some problems with the code, thats the whole point of why i am here. i had 1 picture to look at where i dont see the whole code apperantly, and im not sure if i installed it correctly. if it was working i could easly test it

Comment: [`bbcode_create`](https://secure.php.net/bbcode_create) returns a *resource* that [`bbcode_parse`](https://secure.php.net/bbcode_parse) uses to parse your string.

Comment: Also, doesn't the `showHTML` you've shown do the opposite?  It seems to convert HTML *to* BBCode.

Comment: So, *what* doesn't work with your `bbcode_format` function?  What does it return?

Comment: @RocketHazmat you are looking at the old code i used not the PECL i want to use, but yes the showHTML is copied from where i translate html to bb codes. the problem is that my PECL wont load http://imgur.com/a/ouNAn

Comment: the http://imgur.com/a/ouNAn problem didnt who up before but didnt didnt work then either. if you want i can start a new question with more information on my php.ini the .dll path and so on

Comment: No need to post a new question; you can just edit the one you already have.

Comment: @Volcan3 please use modern solutions for BBCode, I recommend my own library https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Happy to answer any questions.